# R: Making A Map of Canadian Postal Codes

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Here is some background to my question:

- In Canada, each address has a Postal Code (like an American ZIP Code). These Postal Codes are in the format : LETTER NUMBER LETTER - NUMBER LETTER NUMBER (e.g. A1B 2C3)
- The first three characters of a Postal Code is called the FSA - all Postal Codes that share the same first three letters are considered to be within the same FSA
- A free and publicly available "geospatial shapefile" is available online that contains the geographic boundaries of all FSA's in Canada (https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/catalogue/92-179-X)
- **However, there is no such shapefile for Canadian Postal Codes - this is what I am trying to build (i.e. approximate) in R**

To start working on this problem, I found the following link to open data - this contains millions of geocoded Canadian addresses (Postal Codes and Longitude/Latitude coordinates of each individual address): https://www.statcan.gc.ca/en/lode/databases/oda

Here is my plan:

- For a given province in Canada - I can create a "Convex Hull" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) around all addresses of the same Postal Code. This might be able to serve as an "approximate" boundary for each Postal Code.
- If I repeat this for all Postal Codes, I will have an approximate shapefile

**Here is what I tried so far:**

**Step 1:** I downloaded the file (temporary file) for a given province (e.g. Ontario):

```
url <- "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/pub/46-26-0001/2021001/ODA_ON_v1.zip"

temp <- tempfile()

download.file(url, temp)

unzipped_files <- unzip(temp, exdir = tempdir())

csv_file <- unzipped_files[grepl(".csv$", unzipped_files)]


df <- read.csv(unzipped_files[1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Step 2:** Then, using  `lapply`  - I calculated the Convex Hull for all addresses in the same Postal Code using the built-in `chull()` function. Finally, I created a shapefile with the final result:

```
library(sf)

hulls <- lapply(unique(df$postal_code), function(postal_code) {
    chull(df[df$postal_code == postal_code, c("longitude", "latitude")])
})

hull_sfs <- lapply(seq_along(hulls), function(i) {
    st_as_sf(df[df$postal_code == unique(df$postal_code)[i], ][hulls[[i]], ],
             coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
})

hull_sf_combined <- do.call(rbind, hull_sfs)

st_write(hull_sf_combined, "hulls.shp")
```

**Step 3:** As an optional step, we can visualize the final result:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = postal_code)) +
    lapply(seq_along(hulls), function(i) {
        geom_polygon(data = df[df$postal_code == unique(df$postal_code)[i], ][hulls[[i]], ],
                     aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = postal_code), alpha = 0.5)
    })
```

**My Question:** While the code seems to be running, I am not sure if everything I am doing is correct. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

**Note**: Based on the comments provided by @Ben Bolker, is it better to take the geographical centroids of each postal code provided here (https://www.serviceobjects.com/blog/free-zip-code-and-postal-code-database-with-geocoordinates/) and use Voronoi Cells to determine the approximate boundaries?

Comment: though I really like what you are doing, this question could do with a bit more direction/focus - i.e. "I have working code, but I don't know if it is good quality code" is a code review question, not a StackOverflow question

Comment: @ Mark: thank you for your reply and feedback! I worked on this question the whole the weekend - please feel free to edit this question if you think it can be salvaged? thank you so much!

Comment: I think the question has three main parts 1. downloading the data (fine I think) 2. creating the shapes, 3. mapping the shapes. #1 and #3 look okay, it's #2 which is causing you trouble. And that is because of the other question stuff

Comment: As a possibly easier solution: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67154882/190277) gives a link to data containing the **centroids** of postal codes (although it needs to be cleaned a bit, there are a few centroids that show up within the boundaries of the US ...) If you took the centroids and constructed a Dirichlet tesselation/Voronoi diagram, that should give you a pretty good set of polygons ...

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: Thank you so much for your comment (and your previous answer)! In the last week, I have been learning more about Voronoi Diagrams .... based on my (very) limited knowledge of this topic, I think the approach you described makes sense: take the centroid of each postal code and make voronoi polygons until they "collide" with each other ,thus approximating this postal code boundaries. I have started working on this question and will be posting my progress soon ... if you have time, I would be curious to see the specifics as to how you approach this problem.

Comment: Can you please write an answer if you have time? Thank you so much!

Comment: References: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76856093/r-forcing-shapes-to-not-overlap

Comment: References: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76856625/perimeter-of-voronoi-cells

Comment: Can you describe your your final application or a purpose of the resulting map? I.e is it just for visualisation, to estimate postal code area sizes, find a matching code for random coordinates, estimate distances (beteween closes points or perhaps centroids), compare resultibg shapes against some other sgapes (i.e is it ok to use administrative or cencsus divsion shapes in addition to postal codes),... ? I'm mostly tring to figure out if having a  single polygon per postal code is a strict requirement, and if yes, then what might be the reason.

Comment: @margsul: thank you for your reply! currently, this is something very casual and experimental .... I think visualization would be the primary objective... but in the end, I think it would be interesting to answer questions such as creating a heatmap that was colored based on "how many tim hortons restaurants" are inside each postal code (i.e. if i had a dataset that contained the long/lat of each tim hortons...I could then use a spatial join to join this dataset to the voronoi shapefile).... so to answer your question, I think it would be ideal to have one polygon per postal code. thank you!

Comment: Are we on the same page on multipolygon vs polygon in GIS context?  Multipolygon is a set of polygons sharing same attributes, i.e. it's a single record in geospatial dataset (a row  in an sf object) , its area is sum of sub-plyogn areas and centroid calculation considers all sub-polygons. Think of an coastal administrative area that includes some islands; forcing it to a single polygon means dropping all the islands or creating a hull that also includes space between islands.

Comment: A somewhat similar analogy applies here,  creating Voronoi tesselation (for example) from potentially incomplete point dataset is already quite heavy approximation, and dissolving those into single polygons by postal codes, either by dropping potential islands or re-classifying border areas, can only increase error (mis-classified area).  For visualization, it probably would not matter (well.., depends on a scale) , but I'd expect a measurable increase in error rate when using this for reverse geocoding / spatial joins.

Comment: @margusl :thank you for this information! is there some method you would suggest that perhaps I might not have even mentioned?

Comment: this is why I had initially thought that convex hulls might be a better choice ... in the costal example, the voronoi polygons might distort ... but the convex hulls (given the addresses) might be more conservative?

Comment: @margusl: any ideas about this one?

Comment: Sometimes a postal code represents a single building.  Convex hulls will certainly leave gaps in between the polygons (and point sets!).  Separately, you might want to use something like the polyclip package to clip polygons to fix overlaps (or regions extending into the US)

Comment: @Michael Dewar: Thank you for your reply! This is the first time I am hearing about clipping polygons - if you have time, could you please show me how I might be able to use them hear? thank you so much!

Comment: For Voronoi you'd need bounding polygons anyway (cultural / physical ), otherwise, you'll end up just a rectangular tesselation, that's why I asked if it's OK to use administrative or census division shapes -- linked dataset includes census subdivision and province id-s. Note that not all ODA archives include postal codes. One example is Prince Edward Island, the apparent choice for experimenting because of its area and number of addresses. So sorry, for me it seems a bit like a rabbit hole with too many non-coding related unknowns to deliver what was asked. Good luck!

Comment: "However, there is no such shapefile for Canadian Postal Codes" To be clear, those shapefiles DO exist, but they're a commercial product you have to pay for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer dealing with cleaning up your postal code regions.  Suppose you use a convex hull to get a bunch of vertices that define polygons.

```
library(polyclip)
library(ggplot2)

canada <- data.frame(x = c(0,1,1,0),
                     y = c(0,0,1,1))
postcode1 <- data.frame(x = c(0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.8),
                        y = c(0.5, 0.8, 1.5, 1.5))
postcode2 <- data.frame(x = c(0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.25),
                        y = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75))

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = canada, aes(x,y), fill = "lightblue", color = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_polygon(data = postcode1, aes(x,y), fill = "lightgreen", color = "green", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_polygon(data = postcode2, aes(x,y), fill = "pink", color = "red", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

You can see that the convex hulls of the postal code regions overlap each other, and one of them extends outside of the country.  The `polyclip` package lets you take intersections, unions, xor and setdiff of the regions bounded by the vertices.

```
clip1 <- polyclip(postcode1, canada, "intersect")[[1]] |> as.data.frame()
clip2 <- polyclip(postcode2, clip1, "minus")[[1]] |> as.data.frame()

ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = canada, aes(x,y), fill = "lightblue", color = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_polygon(data = clip1, aes(x,y), fill = "lightgreen", color = "green", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_polygon(data = clip2, aes(x,y), fill = "pink", color = "red", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Happy clipping!

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! How would I know how much to clip the polygons?

Comment: First of all, you certainly want to clip the postal code regions so that they intersect with borders of Canada.  If you know they lie within smaller regions like a province or FSA, then intersect with those.  Secondly, if you have overlapping postal codes (which you could find with `polyclip`) then you should decide on some arbitrary way to divide the intersection among them.  Finally, you could take the union of all of your postal code regions, then subtract this from Canada to get the unassigned regions.  Find some sensible way to assign these.

Comment: My advice is assuming the project is non-critical and you prefer a more reasonable (but still a bit incorrect) output over a less reasonable output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This is the first time I have ever heard about clipping in my life ... I am trying to learn more about it. Do you think if you have time, you could please add to your answer and show a real example involving a few real postal codes? thank you so much!

Comment: If you compute a few convex hulls of postal codes and then post the results (either in this question or in a new one) then I can show a bit about the clipping.  Also please provide a polygon for Canada (or whatever sub-region includes your sample postal codes).

Comment: thank you so much! I will start working on making a new question. Do you have any introductory references about clipping polygons? Thank you so much!

Comment: I posted a related question over here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981649/r-clipping-polygons-in-r - can you please take a look at this if you have time? thanks!

Comment: The current posted answer to your new question uses Voronoi approximation and is great.  It does not appear to require polygon clipping.  Also, your question does not start with polygons requiring clipping, so method does not appear relevant to your new question directly.

Answer (score 2):

Readapted from a former adaptation made for Brazil. Colorful, apparently display right mapping for all Canada. Please consider this would be a simple example, nothing robust or elegant:

```
library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggmap)
library(plyr)

area <- readShapePoly("canada.shp")

area.points <- fortify(area)

loc="Toronto"

mapImage <- get_map(location=loc,
                    color="color",
                    zoom=10,
                    maptype="roadmap")

extents <- geocode(loc, output="more")

area.zoom <- subset(area.points, 
                      extents$west  <= long & long <= extents$east &
                      extents$south <= lat  & lat  <= extents$north)

ggmap(mapImage) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long,
                   y = lat,
                   group = group,
                   fill = id),
               data = area.zoom,
               color = 'white',
               #fill = 'black',
               alpha = 0.4) +
  coord_map(projection="mercator")+
  labs(x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude")
```

The MAJOR limitation is you have to change Loc. I am trying to understand how I would have full country coverage. I considered first to a conditional pointing to a vector of Loc, then I would loop while it sweeps through the Loc vectors.

I did not like this because the graphic seems challenged. Need to dig deeper.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! How exactly is this code identifying postal code boundaries in Canada?

Comment: it looks like your approach is using ggmap - this is based on the google API and requires money? I am looking for an open source solution that can be done for free...

Answer (score 1):

Enhancements of **Step 1** invoke checking first the use of an offline backup.
This to avoid unnecessary network traffic between the client and Statistics Canada server.

It is also a good thing to have a backup in case officials restrict or remove public access to data in the future.

Moreover, registering the result of the script given the state of the dataset at a specified time is also a plus.
This is useful for your work consistency if the postal code data may evolve after some period of time.