# R: Forcing Shapes to Not Overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(concaveman)


# simulate data
set.seed(123)

df1 <- data.frame(longitude = rnorm(100,10,1),
                 latitude = rnorm(100,10,1), color = "red")

df2 <- data.frame(longitude = rnorm(100,8,1),
                 latitude = rnorm(100,8,1), color = "blue")

df = rbind(df1, df2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, color=color)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Now, for both colors - I drew "Concave Hulls" and then plotted the results:

```
hull_red_df <- data.frame(longitude = hull_red[, 1], latitude = hull_red[, 2], color = "red")

hull_blue_df <- data.frame(longitude = hull_blue[, 1], latitude = hull_blue[, 2], color = "blue")

hull_df <- rbind(hull_red_df, hull_blue_df)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color = color)) +
  geom_polygon(data = hull_df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group = color, fill = color), alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

**My Question:** Either before the shapes are drawn, while the shapes are being drawn, or after the shapes are drawn - is it possible to somehow add a condition that forces the two shapes not to overlap?

For example - suppose I draw the shape, is it possible to detect if a red point is contained within the perimeter of the blue shape, and to somehow "try again" and "keep trying" until both shapes do not intersect (3 shapes, 4 shapes, etc.)? Is there some "better" type of shape/algorithm that can be used in which this condition is easier to apply?

Thanks!

**Related Question:**

- [R: Making A Map of Canadian Postal Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854004/r-making-a-map-of-canadian-postal-codes)

Comment: hi stats_noob! Can you give an idea of what you want the desired output to be? Do the shapes have to cover every point for each colour, or is it okay to miss some?

Comment: @Mark: thank you for your reply!  Ideally, I would only want  all points of the same color in a given shape ... and no points of another color. If you want some more context, here, is the original problem I am trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854004/r-making-a-map-of-canadian-postal-codes ... thank you so much!

Comment: I guess the point of having some kind of grouping points is to be able to draw conclusions about new points. Do you want your code to be able to generalise to new addresses? Because I don't think a spider-like boundary between postal areas would be beneficial for that (though I may be wrong)

Comment: Here's one thing, which gets you closer: `library(ggvoronoi)
ggplot(df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = color)) +
  geom_voronoi() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))`

Comment: you could take a voronoi diagram like this, or a delaunay triangulation plot, and find triangles which aren't connected (maybe using DFS). Then, if a point cannot be reached, create at the place where there is the shortest distance between two disconnected shapes. Though it's fairly trivial to show that this wouldn't work for everything

Comment: @ Mark: thank you so much for these ideas! I myself have been thinking of approach this problem using evolutionary algorithms (e.g. genetic algorithm). you have red and blue points - and you randomly enclose points in a red shape and a blue shape... you see how many violations (i.e. how many red in blue and how many blue in red) you have, and try to randomly change the perimeters of the shapes until the violations become less and less and eventually become 0.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but do you know that all postal areas are contiguous? Like, in the code for the voronoi diagram, there are islands of red, but it's unclear to me if the underlying reason for that is the postal area is a tentacle that reaches out through the blue, or if it's just an island. It could hypothetically be the case that there used to be a different postal code, and then things were moved across, and there are a few ones that are really old that haven't done it yet

Comment: @Mark: I am no geography expert... but I would like to think that all postal areas are contiguous ( I don't think there will be any tentacle/islands). If this is the case ... does this make the Voronoi approach more suitable?

Comment: I think the voronoi approach is good in that case. It would be interesting seeing some real world data, to see the extent of overlaps

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to get extract the perimeter of each individual Voronoi Cell ... and store all these perimeters within a shapefile? I was able to do this for the Convex Hull approach (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854004/r-making-a-map-of-canadian-postal-codes)

Comment: I think convex/concave hulls like what you were using before would work too

Comment: yeah definitely! it's not my area of expertise, but there's plenty of different packages which implement Voronoi plots. Take a look at ggvoronoi or deldir

Comment: so far, I think I prefer the Voronoi cell approach better ... the convex/concave hulls are producing huge overlaps ...

Comment: interesting! Have you checked if the google maps versions have the same overlaps?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41/seeking-canadian-postal-code-geometries

Comment: thank you for linking this ... unfortunately I have stumbled across this gis link many times .... and always hope that someday I click refresh and some (brilliant) user just so happens to post a link to a full shapefile with canadian postal codes! :)

Comment: rip that's really frustrating!! I might try emailing Statistics Canada

Comment: if you're associated with a university / you know someone who is, you could use this: https://abacus.library.ubc.ca/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:11272.1/AB2/LIKJJX

Comment: Statistics Canada does not have this file ... apparently its owned by Canada Post ...and you have to pay alot of $$$ to get it. at this point I have spent so much time chasing this problem... I kind of want to keep slogging along and create an approximate solution  .... and make it so that anyone in the world who comes across this same problem can benefit from all the time I spent working on it lol!

Comment: In that case, I think the best option is to access things through a library. Maybe if you go to your local university, they would be okay with you accessing it (or if you know anyone who works for or attends a Canadian uni, that could work too)

Comment: https://www.mcgill.ca/library/find/maps/pps https://library.carleton.ca/find/gis/geospatial-data/dmti-national-canmap-suite https://mdl.library.utoronto.ca/collections/geospatial-data/canmap-postal-code-suite-0 etc.

Comment: @ Mark: here is a question I posted on calculating the perimeter of voronoi cells: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76856625/r-perimeter-of-voronoi-cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could re-classify points (or just points in intersecting areas) to simplify border areas, create Voronoi polygons, limit boundary by a concave or convex hull of points and union resulting polygons by updated classification to end up with two non-overlapping polygons, *blue* and *red*

The following example uses k-Nearest Neighbour (`class::knn()`) for re-classification and `geos::geos_concave_hull()` for easy access to concave hull method available in up-to-date `libgeos`. Few different k-values are tested -- with values too low, we'll end up with islands; with values too high, too many polygons will end up on the wrong side of the border.

Depending on your actual use case (does it matter if there are islands of red in blue and vice versa?), you might be better off with `MULTIPOLYGON`s where some sub-shapes end up deep in the neighbouring territory, like with Voronoi polygons that are filled by original *color* value (1st facet on 2nd plot).

And instead of using concave hull to define borders, perhaps consider Voronoi edges for inner borders and administrative shapes for outer borders.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(class)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(geos) 

# simulate data
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(longitude = rnorm(100,10,1),
                  latitude = rnorm(100,10,1), color = "red")
df2 <- data.frame(longitude = rnorm(100,8,1),
                  latitude = rnorm(100,8,1), color = "blue")
df = rbind(df1, df2)

# re-classify with K-Nearest Neighbors, test different k-values
reclass <- c(4,8,10) |>
  setNames(sprintf("color_k%.2d", c(4,8,10))) |> 
  lapply(\(k) knn(train = df[,1:2], test = df[,1:2], cl = df$color, k = k)) |> 
  data.frame()
df <- cbind(df, reclass)

# how classes changed for K = 8:
ggplot(df, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = color_k08, color = color), shape = 21, size = 2, stroke = 1, alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend", name ="fill: re-classified, k = 8") +
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend", name ="outline: original class")
```

[image]

```r
# points  to sf objects
points_sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"))

# concave_hull from {geos}; while it's available in {sf}, it requiers newer geos 
# than the one currently shipped with CRAN {sf} Windows binaries;
# ratio: 1 - convex, 0 -maximum concave-ness
conv_hull_sfc <- geos_concave_hull(st_union(points_sf), ratio = .2) |> st_as_sfc()

# create Voronoi tesselation from points, 
# join all attributes from points sf 
# (color, color_k04, color_k08, color_k10)
voronoi_sf <- points_sf |>
  st_union() |>
  st_voronoi() |> 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON") |>
  st_intersection(conv_hull_sfc) |>
  st_sf(geometry = _) |>
  st_join(points_sf)

# Visualize how different KNN k-values behave
voronoi_sf |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(starts_with("color"), names_to = "type", values_to = "color") |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = color), alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend") +
  facet_wrap(~ type)
```

[image]

```r
# union by color_k10 (as color) whit leaves us with 2 polygons
blue_red_sf <- voronoi_sf |>
  group_by(color = color_k10) |>
  summarise()

# visualize with true point classes
blue_red_sf |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = color), alpha = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = points_sf, aes(color = color), alpha = .8) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend") +
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")
```

[image]

Resulting sf object:

```r
blue_red_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 6.243473 ymin: 5.534102 xmax: 12.18733 ymax: 13.24104
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   color                                                                 geometry
#>   <fct>                                                                <POLYGON>
#> 1 blue  ((7.335231 7.02599, 7.258991 7.170673, 7.158959 7.36051, 7.007493 7.647…
#> 2 red   ((10.1587 8.547543, 9.916631 8.71297, 9.798425 8.65056, 9.712389 8.6051…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ margsul: thank you so much for this wonderful answer! some questions:

Comment: 1) "reclass <- c(4,8,10)" ....this is deciding how many neighbors to run KNN with?

Comment: 2) how do you tell which KNN performed best? in regular supervised classification, you can test the accuracy by seeing how many points were misclassified. can you do the same thing here?

Comment: 3) this approach can also work with multiple colors - correct?

Comment: 4) finally - is it also possible to determine the boundary perimeter of the resulting polygons (e.g. in a shapefile)?

Comment: 1- correct, feel free to test values from 2 to something like 100 or so.  2 - there is no "best", at least not until you define the metric for optimal result (i.e. smallest k that avoids islands). Small K means just high flexibility, likely more wiggly boundary line , islands are probable; while high K results low flexibility, near-linear boundary line,  islands are unlikely to occur. 3 - correct. 4 - that's exactly what the resulting sf object is, set of 2 polygon geometries. Feel free to `st_write()` it to your favourite spatial format, be it GeoJSON, GeoPackage, Shapefile or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Re 2) can you use some classification metric to see how many violations are encountered? E.g. a matrix that shows how many red in blue and how many blue in red?

Comment: I'm sure you can.  But you still have to go through geometries and it becomes a graph problem which I don't believe is in the scope of the answer. If you just want to get the smallest k that would return no islands, a computationally heavy yet simple approach would be to create unions until returned geometry list includes only polygons and not a single multipolygon. Or for quantitative metrics, count the number of sub-polygons in every created union, this will return number of islands. + 1 (for the main shape).

Comment: To the answer of your other Q - https://stackoverflow.com/q/76856625/646761 - I added an example of how one might turn multipolygons to polygons by taking the main shapes and removing holes, is'n that what you are trying to do here but in a way more complicated method? I'd probably use described reclassification only to simplify borders.  To be honest, I'm having a hard time understanding why not just go with mulitpolygons.