# How to approximate polygons (postal code zones) from point data

Tags: r

I have the following dataset in R - this dataset contains a list of geocoded addresses (Canada) with their Postal Codes, Longitudes and Latitudes: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9kjoqsppb85ip0tdc5wmr/stackoverflow_example.csv?rlkey=cwjk222jnoz8c9cgbt01p6bep&dl=0

I loaded this data into R:

```
library(httr)
library(data.table)

url <- "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9kjoqsppb85ip0tdc5wmr/stackoverflow_example.csv?rlkey=cwjk222jnoz8c9cgbt01p6bep&dl=1"

response <- GET(url)

df <- fread(content(response, "text"), sep = ",", quote = "", fill = TRUE)


> head(df)
         "" "latitude" "longitude" "source_id"                   "id" "group_id" "street_no"            "street"       "str_name" "str_type" "str_dir" "unit"     "city" "postal_code"
1: "999976"   44.25845   -76.46308          "" "6baaa1692aaaa7b496aa"    2494328       "104" "POINT ST. MARK DR" "POINT ST. MARK"       "DR"        ""     "" "KINGSTON"     "K7K 6X8"
2: "999977"   44.26391   -76.45090          "" "1f01e7839e59727d95a3"    2508891       "229"      "GREENLEES DR"      "GREENLEES"       "DR"        ""     "" "KINGSTON"     "K7K 6R1"
3: "999978"   44.26262   -76.45164          "" "289d509f161955a7b5ad"    2519600       "443"        "MAUREEN ST"        "MAUREEN"       "ST"        ""     "" "KINGSTON"     "K7K 7M2"
4: "999979"   44.26545   -76.45230          "" "e6516f9c0e173b684627"    2506548       "198"      "GREENLEES DR"      "GREENLEES"       "DR"        ""     "" "KINGSTON"     "K7K 6P7"
5: "999983"   44.23525   -76.49264          "" "2576c9ff82b86638737c"    2508273        "22"         "ELLICE ST"         "ELLICE"       "ST"        ""     "" "KINGSTON"     "K7K 1M5"
6: "999993"   44.26520   -76.45182          "" "03aaecc65f29e1e04fe1"    2507798       "212"      "GREENLEES DR"      "GREENLEES"       "DR"        ""     "" "KINGSTON"     "K7K 6P7"
               "full_addr" "city_pcs" "str_name_pcs" "str_type_pcs" "str_dir_pcs" "csduid"  "csdname" "pruid"         "provider"
1: "104 POINT ST. MARK DR" "KINGSTON"   "PT ST MARK"           "DR"            ""  3510010 "Kingston"      35 "City of Kingston"
2:      "229 GREENLEES DR" "KINGSTON"    "GREENLEES"           "DR"            ""  3510010 "Kingston"      35 "City of Kingston"
3:        "443 MAUREEN ST" "KINGSTON"      "MAUREEN"           "ST"            ""  3510010 "Kingston"      35 "City of Kingston"
4:      "198 GREENLEES DR" "KINGSTON"    "GREENLEES"           "DR"            ""  3510010 "Kingston"      35 "City of Kingston"
5:          "22 ELLICE ST" "KINGSTON"       "ELLICE"           "ST"            ""  3510010 "Kingston"      35 "City of Kingston"
6:      "212 GREENLEES DR" "KINGSTON"    "GREENLEES"           "DR"            ""  3510010 "Kingston"      35 "City of Kingston"
```

**My Question:** Using this data, I am trying to "approximate" the geographical boundary of each Postal Code and visualize the result.

Based on a similar question I posted here ([R: Making A Map of Canadian Postal Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854004/r-making-a-map-of-canadian-postal-codes)), it was suggested to me that a technique called "Polygon Clipping" might be useful for accomplishing this task (i.e. see answer provided by @User: Michael Dewar).

I am trying to learn how "Polygon Clipping" might be useful in accomplishing this task - but I am not sure how to get started with this. **In the end, I would like to have something like a shapefile that contains the "perimeter" (in longitude and latitude coordinates) of each Postal Code.**

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

**Note:**

- Original Source of Full Data : https://www.statcan.gc.ca/en/lode/databases/oda
- **In general, I am open to other ways to solve this problem as well!**

Comment: You can use a Voronoi partition as probably closest guess (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) - but why not just grab the true boundaries? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41/seeking-canadian-postal-code-geometries#62

Comment: @I_O The data are proprietary and they charge $1,950 for one month, or $9,000 per year. Not sure if that's CAD or USD but still

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a Voronoi approximation:

[image: Approximation of postal code zones by Voronoi partitioning]

(Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL.)

---

Here's how, starting from your httr response:

- create point data `d` (*omit the quote argument* from your code, otherwise you'll get funny column names):

```
    d <- data.table::fread(content(response, "text"), sep = ",", fill = TRUE)
```

- set an appropriate projection for the region (Eastern Canada):

```
    my_proj <- '+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs'
```

- create a *spatial* dataframe from `d`:

```
    library(sf)
    library(dplyr)

    the_points <- 
      d |>
      select(longitude, latitude, postal_code) |>
      st_as_sf(coords = c('longitude', 'latitude'), 
               crs = 4326 ## EPSG-code for lon/lat coords
               ) |>
      st_transform(my_proj) |> ## transf. to "Canadian" proj.
      head(100) ## only the first 100 items for demonstration
```

- approximate zones with Voronoi partitioning:

```
    the_zones <- 
      the_points |>
      st_union() |> ## !
      st_voronoi() |>
      st_collection_extract('POLYGON') |>
      st_as_sf() |>
      ## create an ID for later join with postal code:
      mutate(id = paste0('zone_', row_number())) |>
      rename(geometry = x)
```

- get a lookup vector of which postal code (point data) belongs to which zone (polygon data) using `st_intersection` and `pull`:

```
    postal_code_lookup <- 
      st_intersection(the_zones, the_points) |> ## keep only zones around points
      distinct() |>
      as.data.frame() |>
      pull(postal_code, id) ## pulling two cols creates a named vector
    
    the_zones |>
      mutate(postal_code = postal_code_lookup[id])
```

resulting spatial dataframe (for further processing):

```
    + Simple feature collection with 74 features and 2 fields
    Geometry type: POLYGON
    Dimension:     XY
    Bounding box:  xmin: 1554420 ymin: 683010.2 xmax: 1569265 ymax: 698094.6
    CRS:           +proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
    First 10 features:
            id                       geometry postal_code
    1   zone_1 POLYGON ((1554420 697558.1,...     K7K 0C3
    2   zone_2 POLYGON ((1560077 688369.5,...     K7K 1X7
    3   zone_3 POLYGON ((1560089 688314.7,...     K7K 4S4
    4   zone_4 POLYGON ((1554420 688610.3,...     K7K 4W8
    ## ...
```

- vizualize:

```
    library(gglot2)
    library(ggmap)
  
the_zones <- 
  the_zones |>
  mutate(postal_code = postal_code_lookup[id]) |>
  st_transform(4326) ## back to geographic coords

the_background <- get_stamenmap(c(left = -76.46, bottom = 44.25, 
                                  right = -76.42, top = 44.27),
                                zoom = 14
                                )


ggmap(the_background) +
    geom_sf(data = the_zones,  alpha = 0, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_sf_text(data = the_zones, aes(label = postal_code), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_sf(data = st_transform(the_points, 4326), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(-76.46, -76.42), ylim = c(44.255, 44.27)) + 
    theme_minimal()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! this is such a detailed and complete answer! I cant wait to try it out!

Comment: just one question - do you need to pay money to use the ggmap package?

Comment: How many R packages did you pay for using so far? ;-)

Comment: `ggmap` uses google map images which need an API key and possibly paying for once you get to a limit.  https://mapsplatform.google.com

Comment: edit: ggmap *can* use google map images. Other free map image providers are available (but note Stamen Maps is changing its free tier so you might have to pay for that too...)